# Why Maggie never questioned how Seth knows her name is "Maggie"?

Tags: plot-explanation, city-of-angels

In **[City of Angels](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120632/)**, when Maggie & Seth "meet" and Maggie can see Seth they have a conversation.

Seth refers to her name & then she asks how he knows her name is Maggie.

Then he nods towards her ID Card which is hanging around her neck,

After this scene, she checks her ID Card, there is no mention of "**Maggie**"

[image]

So why did she never question Seth about how he knows her name is Maggie?

Comment: She works in a hospital.  There are lots of people who might have told this guy to go find "Dr Maggie Rice" before he actually found her.  (For all she knows, anyway)